# Access to the root controller from area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i have area in my project `Admin` , `User` .

i `Admin` i create a signout buttom . i need when click in signout button go to root and `AccountController` and use `logOff` Action .

i using this but it search in area looking to `AccountController` and `logOff` Action .

```
<li><i class="icon-key"></i>@Html.ActionLink("خروج","LogOff","Account")</li>
```

how can i solve this ?

**Edit**

i used exit code in index view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
                {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <li><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">خروج</a></li>
```

.

```
                }
public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }`
```

Comment: Maybe you can use an href mixed with url.content

Comment: how can ? . . . .

Comment: Something like this should do the trick: `<a href="@Url.Content("~/RootController/LogOff");">Sign Out</a>`

Comment: @Hackerman : no . its not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[HttpPost]` before action. For Ex. this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

and in view part it seems Ok. but just make submit button, like this.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
                {
.... Your Code .....
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

This is true answer if you meaned same i understand from your english.

Answer (score 0):

For the area:

```
Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { Area = "areaName" });
```

If you have some areas in the project then to get "root" controller you might need to do domething like that:

```
Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { Area = "" });
```

So for example:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { Area = "" });">link text</a>
```

Comment: show me this error : >The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Account/LogOff

Comment: Are you sure you have your routing configured properly? Compare url to actions which are working with those which throws 404.

Comment: Show me how you generate links which are working in your application.

Comment: Try to write "area" instead of "Area" in the answer which I've provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126102/discussion-between-kianoush-and-dawidr).